# Create an application for multiple users which will share a common SQL database stored in a Shared Drive

Tags: c#

I want to create an application using VS 2010 and a SQL Database. So, I created a project using VS 2010 and attached it to a SQL database which was created by the SQL server installed on my system. Now I have created an setup.exe file of this project . Its is working fine on my system as SQL server is installed on my system. 
but when I am trying to run it on other system where there is no SQL server installed it is not running . Can you please suggest me as in how to create a .exe file for this.

I want to create an application for multiple users which will share a common SQL datebase stored in a shared drive.

Comment: Are you planning to put the .mdf in a network share and use it from multiple locations? If so, it's not supported and you'll want to set up a dedicated instance of SQL server and point your connection string to that server.

Comment: Ok, so can you Please suggest a way forward as in what I need to do if i want to put a sql database on the network share without setting up a dedicated instance.

Comment: If you really want to use a network share you might want to look at using a Microsoft Access database (yuck). If you already have a server running the files shares, can't you install SQL Server on that? If you have any kind of heavy multiple user use or important data, I'd stay away from using Access on a network drive...

Comment: I don't have access to the server , I can only create folders and put databases files inside the folders on the shared drives. Its is working fine with MS Access.But, the problem is that we have around 120 to 130 users working simultaneously. Can you suggest other databases (MySql , Oracle, etc.) that can be used in the same way as Access and supported by Visual Studio.